# Observe browser window

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable

Is there a way to observe the browser window with an Observable? For example with rxJS or something similar. I'd like to trigger an action every time when the brower window was rescaled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I correctly understood you, you want to observe `window`'s resize event. 
With RxJS it's pretty simple:

```
Rx.Observable
  .fromEvent(window, 'resize')
  .subscribe(event => {
    // output new window width and height
    console.log(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
    // or
    console.log(event.target.innerWidth, event.target.innerHeight)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a new primitive called `ResizeObserver`. It reacts to changes in size of any of the observed elements, independent of what caused the change.

This snippet is from Google Dev Blog:

```
var ro = new ResizeObserver( entries => {
  for (let entry of entries) {
    const cr = entry.contentRect;
    console.log('Element:', entry.target);
    console.log(`Element size: ${cr.width}px x ${cr.height}px`);
    console.log(`Element padding: ${cr.top}px ; ${cr.left}px`);
  }
});

// Observe one or multiple elements
ro.observe(someElement);
```

Unfortunatly `ResizeObserver` is in Chrome 55 Canary, behind the Experimental Web Platform flag. You need a polyfill basically: https://github.com/WICG/ResizeObserver/issues/3